# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') on a recursive component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

After setup the router with:

PostShow > Comments > Comment > Reply
The postShow belong to the stackNavigator!

when click on the comment component to go to reply

show this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

And after search on the docs and the react-navigation issues page and here on SO

the solution seems to place navigation={this.props.navigation} on the child component because is not inside the stack. But still showing the same error after some attempt!

then other solution is to use  withNavigation  on the parent component, still not redirecting to the reply screen!

So, someone please can clarify how to properly use the navigation when the components are recursive or not under the stack or any Navigation component?

```js
<router>    

    export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home
      },

      PostShow: {
        screen: PostShow,

        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: `${navigation.state.params.post.title}`,
          headerTitleStyle,
          headerStyle
        })
      }
    });

    The postSHow component with:

    <postShow>

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,

} from "react-native";


import Comments from "../components/Comments";

class PostShow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: "",
      comments: [],
      comment: "",
      authToken: "",

      position: 1
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.getComments();
  }

   async getComments();

  render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Comments
            comments={this.state.comments}

            //navigation={this.props.navigation}
            //navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <View>
          <View >
            <KeyboardAvoidingView

              keyboardVerticalOffset={80}
              behavior={"padding"}
              style={{
                flex: 1
              }}

            >
              <TextInput
                value={this.state.comment}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholder="Type something nice"
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ comment: text })}
              />

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.submitComment.bind(this)}
              >

                <Text>Send</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default PostShow;

  The comments/comment 
  <comments/comment>


    import Comment from "./Comment";

    class Comments extends Component {

      render() {
        var comments =
          this.props.comments &&
          this.props.comments.map(comment => {
            return (
              <View key={comment.id} style={styles.commentContainer}>
                <Comment
                  // navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}
                  navigation={this.props.navigation}
                  comment={comment}

                />
              </View>
            );
          });

        return <View>{comments}</View>;
      }
    }

    export default Comments;





I'd like to on comment component be able to click on reply and redirect to the screen Reply


        import React, { Component } from "react";

    import { View, Text } from "react-native";

    import Comments from "./Comments";
    import Reply from "./Reply";

    import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
    class Comment extends Component {


      render() {
        const comment = this.props.comment;
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.body}>{comment.comment} </Text>
            <Text
              style={{ color: "blue" }}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Reply")}

            >
              Reply
            </Text>

            <Comments
              // navigation={this.props.navigation}
              // navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}
              comments={comment.replies}

            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Comment` in the `Comments` class, you should forward the `data`.

```js
            <Comment
              // navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}
              navigation={this.props.navigation.navigate("Reply")}
              comment={comment}

            />
...

    const { navigation } = props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.body}>{comment.comment} </Text>
        <Text
          style={{ color: "blue" }}
          onPress={() => navigation}

        >
```

**[Props vs. State](https://blog.cloudboost.io/props-vs-state-in-react-js-9c186dcf39b8)**

Comment: Sorry for the delay! and thank you very much for your time, patience and answer! i checked what you said, but still!

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Your structure is too strange.

Comment: Hong realy thank you very much!
i think i solved i'll test and post here!
seems that your answer is halfway right